# Permalinks problem with custom theme

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, customization

I am pretty much learning by doing a custom theme from scratch (not a child theme), and have had much trouble with permalinks.

In the permalinks settings page on the wp-admin, if I put any option either than the default linking system, all my links result in 404 page not found errors.

I'm not sure if this even exists, but I haven't built a permalink handler function per se. My knowledge of web development (pre-wordpress) makes me want to think that it should though.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what code? You want my index.php?

Comment: You say that when you "put anything other then the default linking system..." you get 404s. Well, what do you "put"? What is that code?

Comment: Editing the post for clarification.

Comment: if you switch to a default theme, do permalinks work as expected?

Comment: Yes, they do work. Can't really use a default theme though, I'm using WP as a CMS instead of a blog.

Comment: WordPress *is* a *CMS*, always. Regardless: the Theme should have no impact whatsoever on permalinks/rewrites. That your custom Theme does is a sign that your Theme is `_doing_it_wrong()`, somewhere. You'll have to find and post the Theme code that is impacting your permalinks/rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you ...

1. Don't have `mod_rewrite` installed or enabled
2. Or your `.htaccess` file in not being edited

To check the first make a file with `<?php phpinfo();` in it, save it to your server-- same place you have Wordpress-- named something like `phpinfo.php`, and load the file in a browser. Look for `mod_rewrite`. It should be near the top in the "Loaded Modules" rows. If it isn't there, the only setting that will work is the default. Unless you can install that module or talk your host into installing it.

As for the second, WordPress should give you message if it can't create/write the `.htaccess` file. When you save the permalinks look for that message. If you see it you will need to copy and paste the `.htaccess` rules into the file by hand or alter the permissions on the server to so that WordPress can write the file.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: I know that my .htaccess is being updated automatically by WP, as I have already fixed that problem.

Will check phpinfo soon.

Comment: Per a recent comment to you question, your permalinks work with the default theme. `mod_rewrite` is not the problem.

Comment: Yep, no mod_rewrite module in phpinfo.

Comment: That is confusing. If there is no `mod_rewrite` none of your permalinks should work. Is this an Apache server? Or IIS? Or something else?

Comment: I'm hosting the site on localhost. I just added mod_rewrite, and phpinfo shows it as expected.

Unfortunately the links still don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going back to permalinks settings page and hitting save again? Sometimes after making edits the permalinks need to be reset by visiting that page and doing nothing but saving.